# playback on NVR according to onvif standard

Tags: c#, onvif

i have a hikvission NVR that connecting with 1 camera, all recorded videos are saved on nvr.
I used the HIK SDK to connect and playback successfully on the NVR but my boss want to use onvif method to find and playback.
I searched for a week how to playback on NVR using onvif but found nothing. i try using onvif device manager but it show only camera, not NVR.
p/s: i am using ispy for development and found some clues.
my clues:
1. GetServices
2. GetRecordingSummary
3. FindRecordings
4. GetRecordingSearchResults
5. GetReplayUri

i tried implement base on document and code in onvif device manager software but not success
http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/recording.wsdl
http://www.onvif.org/ver10/replay.wsdl

**how to implement 5 step above ?**
sorry for the dumb question but i am new with onvif :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Search a lib that match the language you know. You can search here:
   https://www.onvif.org/resources/
2. In each lib, they support method on Onvif specification, include: GetServices, GetRecordingSummary, FindRecordings, GetRecordingSearchResults, GetReplayUri, ... You can write some codes to do this. (Of course, you need a Onvif device (Onvif NVR, Onvif Camera) to comunicate with)
   TIP: If you want to know what the Onvif server sent or received to Onvif device, You can use Wireshark App to catch the packet. I believe you will know more methods